# Optimized MySQl Query Performance with Millions of records table join

Tags: mysql, indexing, query-optimization

I have to insert data in one temporary table using two table Joins.It is taking 30 min to executes completely as one of my table having **hist_data_app** (approximately 300 million) records .I would like to know how i more optimized the query to make it faster.

First Table contains the changelog data with some particular data and other table is having all the data related to that.Below is my both table creation statement.

```
CREATE TABLE `hist_data_app` (
    `product_id` MEDIUMINT(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `application_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `year_id` TINYINT(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `history_id` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `field_name` VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    `old_value` TEXT NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    `new_value` TEXT NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    `comments` TEXT NOT NULL,
    INDEX `ps` (`product_id`, `history_id`)
)

CREATE TABLE `histry_log` (
`history_id` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`history_hash` CHAR(32) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci',
`type` ENUM('products','brands','partnames','mc_partnames','applications') NOT NULL,
`user_id` SMALLINT(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`stamp` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
`source` TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`source_data` TEXT NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci',
`description` TEXT NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci',
PRIMARY KEY (`history_id`),
INDEX `Types` (`type`)
```

)

This is my explain result

```
EXPLAIN
SELECT DISTINCT a.product_id
              , a.history_id
              , a.comments
              , a.field_name
           FROM history_log b
           JOIN hist_data_app a
             ON a.history_id = b.history_id
          GROUP 
             BY product_id;

id select_type table type   possible_keys key     key_len ref                       rows      Extra
 1 SIMPLE      a     ALL    NULL          NULL    NULL    NULL                      278327646 Using temporary; Using filesort
 1 SIMPLE      b     eq_ref PRIMARY       PRIMARY 8       LONGBOW_data.a.history_id         1 Using index
```

history_app_data table

```
product_id  application_id year_id history_id
598865023   12813220945 92  16777304
598865023   12813220945 93  16777304
598865023   12813221222 93  16777304
598865023   12815428123 94  16777304
598865023   12813221833 92  16777304
598865023   12813221833 93  16777304
598865023   12815457549 92  16777304
598865023   12815457549 93  16777304
598865023   12815457549 94  16777304
```

Comment: That said, once you have a valid query, reversing the index will provide a considerable improvement, so (history_id,product_id) - but note that in the absence of a PRIMARY KEY then, in a strict sense, you don't really have a table.

Comment: Selecting columns not listed in GROUP BY and not processed by aggregate function produces non-deterministic result which makes no sense. And using DISTINCT and GROUP BY together makes no sense too.

Comment: @Akina If i removed the group by clause still getting the same explain result

Comment: @Strawberry It is possible - when GROUP BY expression is not included into output list.

Comment: @Strawberry Can you please suggest me to make it more useable and faster ?

Comment: You've completed step one, which was to drop the misleading GROUP BY clause. Step two is to define a PRIMARY KEY on the first table. There will be a step 3, but what exactly it entails depends on step 2

Comment: @Strawberry step two is not applicable in my case as i am having such kind of data in my hist_data_app table

Comment: product_id application_id year_id history_id
598865023 12813220945 92 16777304
598865023 12813220945 93 16777304
598865023 12813221222 93 16777304
598865023 12815428123 94 16777304
598865023 12813221833 92 16777304
598865023 12813221833 93 16777304
598865023 12815457549 92 16777304
598865023 12815457549 93 16777304
598865023 12815457549 94 16777304 </blink>

Comment: If step 2 is not applicable, then use of a relational database management system is inappropriate for your needs

Comment: @Strawberry I have add the what kind of data look like in my table for which you want to me to add primary key. please see above in my description

Comment: So you appear to have a natural PK on (product_id,application_id,year). If so, why not set that as your PK?

Comment: @DRapp Yeah you are right. i only want those records which i have in my histry_log table as mention above.
So my histry_log  table has product and application changed records , i want only application changed records join with my history_data_app table

Comment: @DRapp Like my histry_log  table has 100 records for changed applications so i want only that 100 records out of 300 millions to proceed further but in above case it is not using index and scan full 300 millions records

Answer (score 0):

Based on your response to my comment, you should be good with what you have setup now.  Since your primary consideration would be a single product, your Hist_Data_App table has the index on product_id in the first position which would be what you want, but also having the history_id as well to join to the log table will help.  Just add your where clause and test for some products.

```
SELECT 
      hd.product_id, 
      hd.history_id, 
      hd.comments, 
      hd.field_name
   FROM 
      hist_data_app hd
   where
      -- or whatever single product ID you want
      hd.product_id = 12345
```

Now, I don't know if you really need distinct, but can add that back in no problem.  Since you are not pulling any columns from the log table, you don't even need to join to that table either.  Since you have no aggregations (such as sum, count, avg, etc), you don't need a group by.  I think you had that just in your sample query while pulling ALL your data down so you would not have 300 million rows returned.

Now, to get a better test on time, you may want to sample with some of the products that DO have the most records to see how much time for a single product that literally DOES have the most records.  To get that, you may want

```
SELECT 
      hd.product_id,
      count(*) totalRecsPerProduct
   FROM 
      hist_data_app hd
   group by
      hd.product_id
   order by
      count(*) desc
   limit 10
```

This will get the top 10 products with the most records out of your 300 million, then you can run the prior query against these and see how much REAL time it takes to get the results back.  I think you will see the performance is fine going with your single need product.

Comment: Sure will check.Thanks for your valuable time.

Answer (score 0):

- The query is ill-formed; we should not discuss it until you fix that problem.  Read about "only_full_group_by".
- It is perhaps never 'correct' to have both `GROUP BY` and `DISTINCT` in the same `SELECT`.
- You have the "explode-implode" syndrome.  This is when you do a `JOIN`, which builds a large temp table, followed by a `GROUP BY` to shrink back to what you perhaps had to start with in one of the tables.
- The resultset is still huge; what do you plan to do with the result?
- You really should have a `PRIMARY KEY` on every table.  If this is unique `(history_id, product_id)`, make it the PK.  (Note that I swapped the order, as discussed in other Comments.)
- `year_id` -- Is that the normalization of a `YEAR`?  Not worth it.  Simply have the year in the table; no extra lookup.
- How big is the other table?  (I may be barking up the wrong Optimization.)
- This might give you the same data, but a lot faster:

  ```
  SELECT   a.product_id , a.history_id , a.comments , a.field_name
      FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT history_id FROM  history_log ) AS b
      JOIN  hist_data_app a  ON a.history_id = b.history_id
      GROUP BY  product_id;
  ```

You *will* have to make some structural changes to the tables; plan for some downtime.

If you only need data on Hammers, please show us the `WHERE` clause that would limit the output.  Optimizing for *that* query may be significantly different than the 30-minute query in your Question!

Fix most of what I and others have suggested, then come back with a new Question with fresh schema, etc.  (This Q&A is getting too messy to keep going.)